# Alpine Linux 3.7 でコンパイルした Ruby 2.5.0 が比較的浅い再帰で SystemStackError となる理由を教えてください

Tags: ruby

以下、問題再現のために無理矢理書いたコードです。
(実際は、多少入り組んだ rspec のファイルを rubocop でパースした際に遭遇しました)

```
# test.rb
n = 100000
res = {}
1.upto(n).to_a.inject(res) do |r, i|
  r[i] = {}
end

def f(x)
  x.each_value { |v| f(v) }
end

f(res)
```

このコードを、DockerHub で配布されている Docker イメージ `ruby:2.5.0-alpine3.7` で実行すると、比較的浅い段階で例外になります。

```
% docker container run -v (pwd):/mnt/my --rm -it ruby:2.5.0-alpine3.7 ruby -v /mnt/my/test.rb
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        149: from /mnt/my/test.rb:11:in `<main>'
        148: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        147: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        146: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        145: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        144: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        143: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        142: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
         ... 137 levels...
          4: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
          3: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
          2: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
          1: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
/mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

一方で、Ruby のソース以外は同等である Docker イメージ `ruby:2.4.3-alpine3.7` では比較的深めの段階で例外となります。

```
% docker container run -v (pwd):/mnt/my --rm -it ruby:2.4.3-alpine3.7 ruby -v /mnt/my/test.rb
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux-musl]
/mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
         ... 10067 levels...
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        from /mnt/my/test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

加えて、Debian 版の Docker イメージ `ruby:2.5.0-stretch` で実行すると、比較的深めの段階で例外となります。

```
% docker container run -v (pwd):/mnt/my --rm -it ruby:2.5.0-stretch ruby -v /mnt/my/test.rb
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9878: from /mnt/my/test.rb:11:in `<main>'
        9877: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        9876: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        9875: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        9874: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
        9873: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
        9872: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
        9871: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
         ... 9866 levels...
           4: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
           3: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value'
           2: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `block in f'
           1: from /mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `f'
/mnt/my/test.rb:8:in `each_value': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

この違いは、Ruby によるものでしょうか？それとも Linux (実行環境)によるものでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず、あてずっぽうですが、musl のデフォルトのスレッドスタックサイズが glibc より小さい (https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Thread-stack-size) ことが原因かも知れません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
同じ Alpine Linux 3.7 で同じ様にビルドしている(様に見える) Ruby 2.4.3 では再現しない点がよくわからないのですよね…。